# Python Chain iteration

Tags: iterator, iteration

I really don't know how to do this one smoothly. I'm looking for a combination of zip and flatten that allows for differing length iterators

```
list_of_iterators = [range(0, 3), range(100, 104), range(500, 505)]

iterator_transform = itertools.not_sure_how_to_describe(list_of_iterators)

*iterator_transform
# [ 0, 100, 500, 1, 101, 501, 2, 102, 502, 103, 503, 504]
```

Just wondering if there's a sort of iterator flatten/zipper that does not load the whole iterator and gives me the desired behaviour cleanly?

Comment: Check the [Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) section of the `itertools` documentation for `roundrobin`.

Comment: Much appreciated mate :)